# C# Generic Interface - Implement generalization for specialized interfaces

Tags: c#, generics

Consider the following snippet. How do I correctly implement the `public void GiveFood(IAnimal d)` part? The compiler wants implementations of the 2 separate member interfaces (ISeaAnimal and ILandAnimal) but they are handled by the IAnimal method.

```
    interface IAnimal { }
    interface ILandAnimal : IAnimal { }
    interface ISeaAnimal : IAnimal { }


    interface ICaretaker<in T> where T : IAnimal
    {
        void GiveFood(T d);
    }

    interface ISeaAnimalCaretaker<in T> : ICaretaker<T> where T : ISeaAnimal
    {
        void RefreshWater();
    }

    class SuperCaretaker : ISeaAnimalCaretaker<ISeaAnimal>, ICaretaker<IAnimal>
    {
        public void RefreshWater()
        {
            // ...
        }

        public void GiveFood(IAnimal d)
        {
            // ...
        }
        // ---> The below methods are redundant since GiveFood(IAnimal) is implemented, but the compiler wants them still
        //public void GiveFood(ISeaAnimal d)
        //{
        //    throw new NotImplementedException();
        //}
        //public void GiveFood(ILandAnimal d)
        //{
        //    throw new NotImplementedException();
        //}
```

Comment: Maybe you just want `class SuperCaretaker : ISeaAnimalCaretaker<ISeaAnimal>` and `public void GiveFood(ISeaAnimal d)` Though its hard to know what you are designing here

Comment: The compiler doesn't want the `GiveFood(ILandAnimal d)`... `ILandAnimal` is irrelevant.

Comment: `void ISeaAnimalCaretaker<ISeaAnimal>.GiveFood(ISeaAnimal d) => GiveFood((IAnimal)d);` Then put your implementation in the other method. This documents (a) that you are aware that you could use a different implementation when invoked through the sea animal caretaker interface but (b) that you do not want to use that option at the moment and just refer to the generic method instead. C# just does not support contravariant input types for interface implementations.

Comment: Thanks @Heinzi, I can live with that workaround if i _know_ that it is not supported. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

How about using an explicit interface implementation? Note that `SuperCaretaker` implements both `ICaretaker<IAnimal>` and `ICaretaker<ISeaAnimal>`:

```
class SuperCaretaker : ISeaAnimalCaretaker<ISeaAnimal>, ICaretaker<IAnimal>
{
    public void RefreshWater()
    {
        // ...
    }

    public void GiveFood(IAnimal d)
    {
        // ...
    }

    void ICaretaker<ISeaAnimal>.GiveFood(ISeaAnimal d) => GiveFood(d);
}
```

This way the `ISeaAnimal` method is hidden, unless you access it using an expression of type `ICaretaker<ISeaAnimal>` or `ISeaAnimalCaretaker<ISeaAnimal>`. This also means that you can just call `GiveFood(d);` in the implementation without causing infinite recursion.

You don't need the `GiveFood(ILandAnimal)` method, since `SuperCaretaker` doesn't implement `ICaretaker<ILandAnimal>`, but if it does (I don't see why you need to though...), you can write another explicit interface implementation.

Comment: Yes, add a (dynamic)d otherwise youre in a ... stackoverflow :) but that seems like the best way

Comment: dynamic? what? no. Just make sure to cast the argument to match the overload you want.

Comment: @JeremyLakeman I don't think you need to cast, or use dynamic. Since the `ISeaAnimal` method is an explicit interface implementation, it's hidden when you access it from `this`. In fact, I think using dynamic will cause a stack overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the ISeaAnimalCaretaker implementation from SuperCaretaker class, so you can handle IAnimal instances.

Like this:

```
class SuperCaretaker :  ICaretaker<IAnimal>
    {
        public void RefreshWater()
        {
            // ...
        }

        public void GiveFood(IAnimal d)
        {
            // ...
        }

        // You don't need the other method anymore

}
```

Comment: I see what you mean but the point is that the class _does_ implement the interface.